# ESP32-WROOM-32D need to press reboot to start working

Tags: pcb-design, esp32

I have made a PCB based on the ESP32-WROOM-32D, and the code upload correctly, but it seems that the board for start to work it has to press the reboot button first.

Based on the schematic that ESPRESSIF give us for the ESP32-DevKitC V4. One of the difference between our schematic is how they the get 3.3V.

We use a step-down to go from 12V to 3.3V:
[image]
[image]
[image]

And they used the AMS1117 to go form 5V to 3.3V. (https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/esp32_devkitc_v4-sch.pdf)
[image]
[image]

That anyone knows if this matter? or what else can i try?

Comment: Please post either the full schematic or at least a link to the schematic used. How are you programming the ESP? Does it work as you expect after reboot?
It's unlikely to be a problem with the 3v3 generation, it's more likely something's wrong with the reset circuit

Comment: Yes it works fine after I press the reboot. Or if I open the Serial monitor, also works fine

Comment: C28 should be a bit "higher" ... 1 uF (?)

Comment: I already try that and it didnt work

Comment: Did you insert some "delay" in the - void setup -? R10 & R11 too low 150 Ohm -> 1k Ohm ?

Comment: I have just insert a delay of 1000ms, but nothing

Comment: Actually. I remove the leds D4 and D6. Because it didnt allow me to upload the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try the solution that is proposed here: https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=6090

And it works! I remove the capacitance C31

[image]